# Datatables multi-column sort - help required with specification

Tags: jquery, datatable

This is my first time trying to do a datatables multi column sort and I just need some help on whether or not what I have specified will work the way I want it to.

I have the following table.

[image]

What I want is for datatables to:

- sort by the third column (Conn Status) desc with it's secondary sorting coming after. If the third column is sortable the sorting rules specified for subsequent columns don't need to be applied.
- If the third column has all the same values and therefore sorting cannot be applied I would then like it to sort by column 5 desc (mdi) with it's secondary sorting after. If the fifth column is sortable the sorting rules specified for subsequent columns don't need to be applied.
- If the fifth column has all the same values and therefore sorting cannot be applied I would like it to sort by column 7 (DSM) desc with it's seconday sorting after. If the seventh column is sortable the sorting rules specified for subsequent columns don't need to be applied.
- If the seventh column has all the same values and therefore sorting cannot be applied I would then like it to sort by column 1 (SiteId) asc.

This is what I have attempted so far but I'd like a bit of help if possible. Also how can I specify the desc part of the sort (at the moment I can only figure out asc.

```
  $("#storeHealthTbl").dataTable ({
      "bSort": true,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bPaginate": false,
      "aoColumnDefs": [ {
          "aTargets": [ 2 ],
          "sType": "string",
          "aDataSort": [ 2, 4, 6 ] /* Want 2,4,6 to be desc but don't know how*/
      }, {
          "aTargets": [ 4 ],
          "sType": "string",
          "aDataSort": [ 4, 6 ] /* Want 4,6 to be desc but don't know how*/
      }, {
          "aTargets": [ 6 ],
          "sType": "string",
          "aDataSort": [ 6 ] /* Want 6 to be desc but don't know how*/
      }, {
          "aTargets": [ 0 ],
          "sType": "numeric",
          "aDataSort": [ 0 ] /* This one is asc */
      }, ]
  });
```

I should also mention that the columns with images in them will have an alphabetic "X" at certain times and hence this is how I expect the sort to work. If there is no "X" and they are all green images(i.e. Not a alpha character" then I would like to jump to the next sort I have specified).

Hope this makes sense.

I am using data tables 1.9.4.

thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, if column 4 has different values and can be sorted, should sorting end there or should column 7 also be sorted?

Comment: and what version of DataTables are you using, believe me, that's important.

Comment: I'll get the answer to my version in a couple of hours and will also clarify on your over question. Sit tight until then

Comment: i've updated my post with the version of datatables and I also changed my code snippet a little bit to properly reflect what I was attempting to do. If column 5(MDI) has different values and can be sorted then sorting rule should be [ 4 desc, 6 desc] and sorting can end there. That goes for all the other rules too. As soon as one of the rules are met, sorting can stop there (but secondary sorting should still be applied). I've updated to post to try and explain this.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "with it's secondary sorting coming after" a little more. Or rather, could you list what secondary sort should be applied for each rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any built in functionality that would accomplish this level of conditional sorting. If you don't mind using the programmatic equivalent of a hammer, the below should do the trick.

Note that I may not have the sort orders right for what you want but you can change that easy enough.

Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/e5s8toLj/5/)

```
// function to check our conditions and set the proper sort order
function getSortOrder(sortCols, sortVars) {
    var set = false;
    // loop through our array of columns to check
    $.each(sortCols, function(ind, elm) {
        // create a var to hold the value in this column on the first row
        var firstVal;
        // loop through each row
        $("#datatable").find('tr').each(function(tri, tre) {
            // stop checking if we already found a column with different values
            if (!set) {
                // otherwise, et get the value in this column on this row
                var curCellVal = $(this).find('td').eq(sortCols[ind]).text();
                // row 0 is a header row, do nothing 
                if (tri == 0) { 
                } else if (tri == 1) { // for first actual row, set `firstVal` to its value
                    firstVal = curCellVal;
                } else { // if after first row, check current row's cell value against 'firstVal'
                    // if the values are different, this column can be sorted, 
                    if (curCellVal != firstVal) {
                        // flag as set so the function stops looking
                        // this could probably be done better
                        set = true; 
                         // initialize datatable with the sort order at the current index of `sortVars`
                        initDTWithSortOrder(sortVars[ind]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    // default initialization if not caught by our function
    var datatable = set ? null : $("#datatable").dataTable(); 
};
// `getSortOrder()` takes two parameters
// parameter 1: array: columns to check
// parameter 2: array: sort values (each being a  muti-dimensional array: [column, direction] )
getSortOrder([2, 6, 8, 0], [
    [[2, 'desc'],[4, 'desc'],[6, 'desc']], // sort order to use is column 3 is not all the same value
    [[4, 'desc'],[6, 'desc']],             // sort order to use is column 7 is not all the same value
    [[8, 'desc']],                         // sort order to use is column 9 is not all the same value
    [[0, 'asc']],                          // sort order to use is column 1 is not all the same value
]);

function initDTWithSortOrder(sortOrder) {
    $("#datatable").dataTable({
        "bSort": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "aaSorting": sortOrder
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed. It's an excellent tutorial for me and others to learn more about datatables. But it has also helped me with some general jquery knwoledge.